# Update Model value in ajax post in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have to update my model and then my view in jquery ajax post

below is my textbox

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Gender

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

i am having another normal textbox with read only false. White updating this second input box this first box need to be update (like angular but i dont want to use any template) with value given in post

Ajax post that called on second textbox focusout

```
function onChange(args) {
        var value = JSON.stringify({ empcode: 0});
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCode1", "Button")',
            data: value ,
            contentType: 'application/json',


        });
    }
```

Here i am getting my value properly and i am posting this to below controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCode1(Gender empcode)
    {
        return PartialView("UpdateCode1", empcode);
    }
```

but its not updating textboxfor value

Any suggestion?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the view content that is being returned from `UpdateCode1`. You need to handle the result of the AJAX request: `$.ajax(...).done(function(viewContent) { /* update the UI with viewContent */ });` You also don't really need to stringify your `value`.

Comment: i want to update automatically with view return

Comment: You need a function in Ajax to get the response and update the the field you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function on success of the ajax to perform what needs to be done with the response of the ajax call.

```
    $.ajax({
        type...
        .... json',
        success: function (response) { 
            $("#DivSelector").html(response);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

And make a div surrounding the first text box so that the content can be refreshed after ajax call.

```
   <div id="DivSelector">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
   </div>
```

If just to update one textbox with other textbox content is the requirement then why need ajax and controller ?? Can be just done with jquery alone.